# Why incorrect controller file nesting is not error in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my config routes:

```
...
scope module: :public do
  ...
  scope module: :doctor do
    get 'vets/new', to: 'vets#new'
    ...
  end
end
```

So, the nesting is: public -> doctor -> vets.
By accident, I put vets controller into a **public** folder (`app/controllers/public/vets_controller.rb`), wrapped it into Public module. And also put an appropriate view: `app/views/public/vets/new.html.slim`.
This stuff is working correctly on my local machine, but after the deployment process, I get 404  error.

How can I turn this check on in development mode? I need to know about this type of issues on the development stage.

Why do you think it even works on my local machine?

Comment: You're miissing the doctor scope in your paths

Comment: @Waclock it is the point. It's a bug but Rails didn't inform me about this until I deployed this code on a server

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation that include `scope module: "etc"` only ever use 1 level of nesting.

Using 2 levels of `scope` nesting wasn't how it was intended to be used. It's a bug that Rails doesn't notice these errors in development.

To get the errors that you want, change some of the configuration options in your `development.rb` file. Notice how they are different from your `production.rb` file.

```
# config/environments/development.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # more code
end
```

To

```
# config/environments/production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. 
  # This eager loads most of Rails and your application in memory, 
  # allowing both threaded web servers and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # more code
end
```